# how to create index in two table mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Please help me to create index between two tables in mysql? I have "account" and "group" table. I have to index with "group_id with index_id" and to be unique.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by "be unique" ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL table indexes are on single tables.

Perhaps you're thinking of [a FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), which is only available with the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned this myself, [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread286239.html), but apparently if you create a Unique constraint on a field, mySql will automatically create a nonclustered index on that field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a Foreign key.

This statement assumes that 'group_id' is a column in the account table and 'index_id' is a column in the group table.

```
ALTER TABLE account ADD CONSTRAINT group_index FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES  group (index_id)
```